# 3 Divs on Top Middle and Bottom

Tags: jquery, html, css

I require 3 Divs on top, middle and bottom

[image]

I have used a jquery to get the viewport height and applied a percentage of the same to the respective Top and Bottom divs only. However when I resize the page, things look ugly as the middle div overlaps the rest or vice versa. I need to maintain the margin of the middle div (as shown in the pic, which is around 10px)

Here is my Javascript

```
$(document) .ready (function(){

function thirty_pc() {
var height = $(window).innerHeight();
var thirtypc = (40 * height) / 100;
thirtypc = parseInt(thirtypc) + 'px';
$(".botline,.topline").css('height',thirtypc);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
thirty_pc();
$(window).bind('resize', thirty_pc);
});

});
```

Is there any way the same can be done using CSS or with JQUERY.

Looking forward for your help.
Thank you.

Comment: I have just updated my query. I require the top and bottom divs extend full in height to cover the view port, except the middle portion. The top and bottom will have some background pictures too.. Thank you

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/omo5wab9/9 it's just CSS no JS/jQ. Not very complex, just try it once and you'll see it's a better alternative. This generator can help you get started http://css3gen.com/css3-flexbox/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/omo5wab9/6/)**

Try using [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). It's pure CSS and all modern browsers are [compatible](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)

**HTML**

```
<div id="mainFlex">
    <div id="box1">❶</div>
    <div id="box2">❷</div>
    <div id="box3">❸</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
    div {
    border: 3px solid red;
    margin: 10px;
}
#mainFlex {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: box;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    box-pack: center;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-box-align: stretch;
    ox-align: stretch;
    border: 1px dashed blue;
}
#box1 {
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 1;
    box-ordinal-group: 1;
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    box-flex: 0;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 100px;
}
#box2 {
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 2;
    box-ordinal-group: 2;
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    box-flex: 0;
    height: 100px;
}
#box3 {
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 3;
    box-ordinal-group: 3;
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    box-flex: 0;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Sir, I have updated my query, I require the top and bottom divs to extend fully. Also the same to be responsive. Thank you

Comment: Yeah, flexbox is designed for that as the demo shows, use vw and vh units instead. http://demosthenes.info/blog/660/Using-vw-and-vh-Measurements-In-Modern-Site-Design

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/omo5wab9/9/ This demo shows the use of vh and vw on the container `#mainFlex` and the `box-flex` set to 2 for the expanding boxes #1 and #3

Comment: Shall give a try.. But when I resize the DEMO.. The height of 1 and 3  divs do not extend fully. Please have a look. Thank you

Comment: My bad, the vw and vh were reversed, it should work as expected https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/omo5wab9/11/